# How to implement multiselect checkbox dropdown using stimulus js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, stimulusjs

I am new to stimulus js so bear with me. Is there any library for stimulus js to implement a multi-select checkbox dropdown? Similar to jquery bootstrap multi-select. I tried to search a lot but didn't get any relevant solution

I have only found below links but those aren't helpful 
[Link 1](https://github.com/stimulus-components/stimulus-checkbox-select-all) 
[Link 2](https://github.com/rbague/stimulus-check-all) 
[Link 3](https://github.com/github/check-all) 
[Link 4](https://www.stimulus-components.com/docs/stimulus-checkbox-select-all/)

I am looking for a UI like the one below. When you click on the dropdown it should open multiselect checkboxes. User can select  Minimum 0 and Max 2 options
[image: UI]

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Please explain more clearly what do you want to implement.

Comment: @janpeterka I have updated the question. Let me know if you need more information